# Receive SMS messages from a Huawei dongle

Tags: networking, usb, software-installation

I have settled up my internet connection as described at [it's a clean machine blog](http://itsacleanmachine.blogspot.com/2012/11/raspberry-router.html) . I've settled everything up. However, my ISP informs me by an SMS that I'm getting close to the monthly FUP, and I have no other way how to get this information. Is it possible to receiver SMS messages on my Huawei E220 dongle? I'm then able to set up a cron system that would send me the SMS messages on my e-mail.

Answer (score 4):

you might be able to get your SMS messages by outputting some AT commands to your modem:

```
$ echo 'AT+CMGF=1' > /dev/ttyUSB1
$ echo 'AT+CMGL="ALL"' > /dev/ttyUSB1
```

and view the results in another window, where you catch the output using:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyUSB1
```

([source](http://blog.vinceliu.com/2009/05/huawei-e220-modem-on-linux.html))

Comment: ok, I'll try. One more question: There're too `tty`'s for this device, `ttyUSB0` and `ttyUSB1` -- why is that? I obviously use `ttyUSB0` for ISP, does it mean I have to use the other one for SMS? Is there any difference between them? Thx!

Comment: Seems like the `/dev/ttyUSB0` is the interface to connect to the mobile phone provider, and the `/dev/ttyUSB1` is the interface in which you can issue AT commands to and read the response back from.

Comment: As far as I can tell this deletes the messages from the modem, so be sure you have a working terminal, e.g. make sure `AT` produces an `OK`.

Comment: @lenik On my Huawei modem, it is actually reverse. I can only establish a PPP connection via `/dev/ttyUSB1` and can use `/dev/ttyUSB0` for anything else, e.g. reading SMS, statistics and connection parameters.